# Url doesnot opens on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have strange problem. Basically I have a Universal app that opens a link that takes to my other apps in the app store.The code I am using is

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=somenumber&mt=8";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

This works perfectly on iPhone, However on iPad it says "Request could not be completed".

Comment: Where does it say "Request could not be completed"?  Console?  Modal popup box?  App store?

Answer (score -1):

It won't open because the link is pointing to an iPhone/iPod app on the App Store, therfore it cannot be installed on the iPad.

Comment: That's just false. You can install iPhone/iPod apps on your iPad.

Comment: I do agree with Daniel.I am able to open the link using some other id, but not clear why the id I want to use is not working